# Using PHP to generate screenshots from an HTML source

Tags: php, image

I've got an idea for a site that would generate png or jpeg screenshots of webpages on the fly. The end user would never see the pages, but the HTML would be turned into a screenshot instead and the end user would see that screenshot.

How can I get started on this? I guess what I'm looking for is some kind of PHP function that takes the HTML as an argument and then produces an image file in a specified location.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to duplicate functionality that is mastered by others: http://browsershots.org/ (site testing) and http://www.thumbshots.com/ (site thumbs)

Comment: I think you're looking for a "website thumbnail generator." Do a Google search for "PHP thumbnail generator" and see what comes up. What you want is sufficiently complex: it's essentially a browser that outputs to an image file instead of to a screen.

Comment: See similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=screenshots+with+php

Comment: Thanks guys - it looks like this is going to be more complicated that I first thought. I guess I was just looking for a create_image(path/to/image/image.png, webpage.html) function, but no such luck. I'll have to give it more time later.

For the record, I'm looking to dynamically create screenshots of pages as they are generated by a CMS, so the browsershots.org and thumbshots.org sites aren't really up to it. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, PHP does not do this.

You can, however, find a solution using external tools.
Here is how I would do it

1. Generate the HTML
2. I would pass this HTML to a external tool using exec. There is, for instance [this one](http://www.karakas-online.de/myLinuxTips/html2png.html).
3. Then, display the generated picture

Answer (score 1):

http://www.zubrag.com/articles/create-website-snapshot-thumbnail.php